# Eventlistener click is not working on ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to create a code where if you click a specific part of a position on the screen(map), returns the position of the map and the nearest restaurant that is nearby.

But apparently, my implementation of eventListener is not working.

Here's my myinfo.ejs.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/views/style.css">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="../views/myinfo.css"  />
    <div class="basic">
        <div class="photo"><img class="photo1" src="../images/profile/<%= session.image%></div>

    <div class="photo">
        </div>
    <div class="intro">
        ID: <% for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %> 
            &nbsp <% } %> 
        <span class="intronb"><%= session.user %> </span> <br /> <br />
        이름: <% for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %> 
            &nbsp <% } %> <span class="intronb"><%= session.name %></span>

    </div>
     <div class="group">
        <div class="visited">
        이번 달 방문한 횟수는
        </div>
        <div class="rank">
        등수.
        </div>
        <div class="favourite">
        한식.
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="displaytext">
        선택된 음식점:  <div class="rt"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="map">
          ABadfafasf
      </div>
           <script src="../views/click.js"> </script>   



    </div>
</html>
```

and here's my javascript code.  click.js.

```
let clickArea = document.querySelector('.map');
console.log("hi" + clickArea); //this Works. returns hi[object HTMLDivElement] but the problem is that getClickPosition seems like it doesn't run. or maybe clickArea.addEventListener.

let rtname = document.querySelector('.rt');

clickArea.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

function getClickPosition(e) {
    var xpos= e.clientX;
    var ypos = e.clientY;
    console.log(xpos + " " + ypos);

    var restaurants = [["chicken", [500, 600]]];

    for (var i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
        if (abs(xpos - restaurants[i][1][0]) < 5 && abs(ypos - restaurants[i][1][0] < 5)) {
            rtname.innerHTML = restaurants[i][0];
        }
    }
}
```

have changed map size to the entire screen to check if it was the size of the div, but still was not working. How could I fix this?

Comment: It should work - https://jsbin.com/zejadokeye/edit?html,js,console,output. Maybe it something else. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yeah. but still, it's working inside the link. However, it's probably not working  on localhost because it's ejs..?  I have no idea. does the eventlistener work the same on ejs?

Comment: As much as I know, ejs is eventually been converted to an html file so the javascript doesn't know if it came from ejs or not. Are there errors in the console? If so, they might tell us what's the problem..

Comment: Thanks for the help Mosh! However, I've not been still able to fix this issue. If you do not mind, would you mind taking a look at my github? https://github.com/hbin0701/ronal-hwang